# What are these things that appeared in my backyard and front lawn?

Tags: backyard

[image]

These things appeared all around my house. It was done while I was away. I live in The Woodlands, TX

Comment: Any other/bigger pictures?  Kinda looks like a termite bait station with the cover missing, but hard to tell from that one small pic.

Comment: Is that an in ground sprinkler ? The pic is not well focused did you just notice them?

Comment: If you own the property then i have to ask,  Who put them there?

Answer (score 3):

It is a termite bait station, used to give subterranean termites an easy way to get what they think is food, carry it back to their nest and distribute it to all, killing the entire colony.

[image]

Most likely your property has a lot of dead wood on it and is harboring termite colonies that are then migrating and attacking your neighbors, so they put the stations out in your property because you were not there. I've had to do that myself when a neighbor basically negleted her house and the entire thing became one giant termite colony.